# How to send Secure WebSocket through http proxy

Tags: android, sockets, proxy, websocket, network-programming

I am trying to reach the [WebSocket Echo Server](http://www.websocket.org/echo.html) with the help of the [Weberknecht WebSockets](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht) through [little proxy server](http://www.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/). I was able to [reach ws:// Websocket with the help of this link](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/websocket_via_http_proxy). But my requirement is for wss:// (WebSocket Secure) to reach out the server through [proxy](http://www.littleshoot.org/littleproxy/).

I was not able to achieve this. I googled but got only got [descriptive](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers) links but not a sample code. Stackoverflow links were also of not much use.
1) [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18294586/proxying-websockets-through-node-http-proxy-doesnt-work)
2) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822000/websockets-wss-and-proxy-server-with-asynchttpclient)

Steps i followed are
1) Create a normal socket and do a CONNECT to proxy as [described here](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/websocket_via_http_proxy).
2) Upgrade the [socket from plain socket to SSLSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559859/is-it-possible-to-change-plain-socket-to-sslsocket)
3) Now try reaching echo webserver on wss (443) port.

Getting an error saying connection closed and some times "plain socket?" kind of exception.

Please let me know if any has tried the same and also redirect me to the proper link.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in communicating wss://echo.websocket.org via a proxy server using [nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) library.

```java
private static WebSocket connect() throws Exception
{
    String PROXY  = "http://......";
    String SERVER = "wss://echo.websocket.org";

    return new WebSocketFactory()
        .getProxySettings()
        .setServer(PROXY)
        .getWebSocketFactory()
        .setSSLContext(NaiveSSLContext.getInstance("TLS"))
        .createSocket(SERVER)
        .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter()) {
            ......
        }
        .connect();
}
```

See "[WebSocket client library (Java SE 1.5+, Android)](http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2015/05/websocket-client-library-java-se-15.html)" for details.

Comment: It might also be possible with https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues/672 and using the latest code of that library (in master for planned release 1.5.2)